# Matrices determined by certain marginals with respect to the partial trace.

Tags: matrices, kronecker-product

Suppose $A_i$ is a matrix algebra for $i=1,...,n$ (i.e., $A_i$ consists of $n_i\times n_i$ matrices with complex entries), and suppose $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are elements of $A_1\otimes \cdots \otimes A_n$ satisfying the following properties:

1. $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are both Hermitian.
2. $\text{tr}_{A_1\otimes \cdots \otimes \widehat{A_i}\otimes \cdots A_n}(\tau)$ and $\text{tr}_{A_1\otimes \cdots \otimes \widehat{A_i}\otimes \cdots A_n}(\sigma)$ are both invertible for $i=1,...,n-1$ ($\widehat{A_i}$ denotes the empty algebra and $\text{tr}_{(*)}$ is the partial trace).
3. $\text{tr}_{A_1\otimes \cdots \otimes\widehat{A_{i-1}}\otimes \widehat{A_{i}}\otimes\cdots \otimes A_{n}}(\sigma)=\text{tr}_{A_1\otimes \cdots \otimes\widehat{A_{i-1}}\otimes \widehat{A_{i}}\otimes\cdots \otimes A_{n}}(\tau)$ for $i=2,...,n$.

Then can we conclude that $\tau=\sigma$?

Comment: The problem looks similar to what is known as the quantum marginal problem, except in that case $\tau$ and $\sigma$ would be positive semidefinite and have unit trace.